# I need to insert text to a file with quotes using sed

Tags: sed

Hi Stackoverflow users,

Normally I can use sed pretty wel (often need a few tries). However I am having issues with adding the text below at the end of the file:

```
<linebreak/empty line here>
[extensions]
blacklist = "google-authenticator"
```

Into a file called: /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/panel.ini

To make things "more" complicated, I also use the command in OpenVZ automation. Like this:

```
vzctl exec $VEID 'sed XX "VALUE FROM ABOVE" /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/panel.ini'
```

Can someone provide some help and/or direct me in the right direction?

Obviously I tried a few things, but I think I am having issues with the extra quotes in the text I am trying to add.

Errors are always something like this:

- expression #1, char 89: unterminated address regex
- expression #1, char 91: unterminated address regex
- expression #1, char 53: unterminated address regex

So I am doing something wrong and I have no clue how to correctly add the above. Preferably with a line-break in front.

I hope I explained the issue correctly. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

//Edit

All I need is a solution to add the following text:

```
<linebreak/empty line here>
[extensions]
blacklist = "google-authenticator"
```

by using sed.

So I can apply it to my script which creates an OpenVZ container (automated) like: vzctl exec $VEID 'possible sed solution here' /file-name

Sorry if I wasn't clear before.

Comment: Do you just require escape characters for Sed?

Comment: I tried it before with escape characters, but then I received the mentioned errors. I didn't save the examples I tried. But probably I did it wrongly?

Comment: Why don't you just use `cat` to append two files?

Comment: @kvantour I am using an automated script to setup an OpenVZ container, so I don't think it's easy to use cat to append the files all together. That's why I asked a solution or idea based on sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this [`GNU sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
'sed -i '\''$a \\n[extensions]\nblacklist = "google-authenticator"'\'' /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/panel.ini'
```

- `-i`: edit files in place
- `$`: address matching the last line
- `a text`: append text after a line

Just like [@Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent) recommended in his deleted answer, it would be more readable and simpler to save the text you want to append into a file and use the `r file` command to `sed`.

Comment: Thank you PesaThe! And thank you for the explanation as well!
After looking at your code I discovered what I did wrong before; I didn't use '\' as you did. And now it works, even from the vzctl command. Also I learned a lot of your solution. I will have to dive into the "r file"-command, but I didn't understand it at all. And it's not that I use sed on a daily basis. Anyways thank you again for the example/solution and explaining things! Highly appreciated. You made my day! ;-)